# PHP Contact Form with Network Solutions

Tags: php, contact-form

Have a basic contact form using https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer on a Network Solutions shared hosting package.

```
// start the mail request basics
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = 'my_gmail_account@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '*******';
```

Everything works find locally (on my computer) and form sends email, but when I upload this php file to our network solutions hosting I get the following Error.

```
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
SMTP connect() failed.
```

Is there something wrong with my Mail Settings?  Anyone else had success with PHP mailing on Network Solutions Shared Hosting?

Comment: Was there ever a solution found for this? 5 years later and having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Network Solutions blocks several ports required to send mail including those needed for gmail.

If anyone finds an alternate, please let me know.

For now, used a dummy account and used standard PHP mailer then forwarded mail.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your config options like this.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "my_gmail_account@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "********";
$mail->SetFrom("somemail@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Testing the New Config";
$mail->Body = "Hey there !";
```

Comment: That was my initial config, but got same response > Failed to connect to Server

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with these settings:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    "ssl" => array(
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false,
        "allow_self_signed" => true
    )
);
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->Host = "email-out-priv.myregisteredsite.com";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = "noreply@mydomain.com";
$mail->Password = "********";
```

You have to pay for an email address with Network Solutions for a domain you own.  You can see the host and port by logging into your mailbox (mail.mydomain.com) --> Top right Menu --> Settings --> Mail --> Mail and Social Accounts --> E-Mail (Edit) --> Outgoing server (SMTP).  I used this [PHP Mailer Documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#godaddy) as a clue to this solution.